# How to prettyprint json using jq standalone?

Tags: text-formatting, json, jq

Currently, when I want to pretty-print a json file using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), I use:

```
cat file.json | jq .
```

Yet I would expect for `jq` to accept a file name as argument without having to fallback on `cat`.

The man page says:

> jq [options...] filter [files...]
>
> ...
> By default, jq reads a stream of JSON objects (whitespace separated)
> from stdin. One or more files may be specified, in which case jq will
> read input from those instead.

Yet running:

```
jq file.json
```

fails by throwing compile errors that the keys are not defined.

How am I supposed to add the file when running `jq`?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

```
jq . file.json
```

is what I was looking for. I didn't realize that the `.` is a [filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) and not a placeholder for the piped in content:

> `.`
>
> The absolute simplest (and least interesting) filter is `.`. This is a
>   filter that takes its input and produces it unchanged as output.

And the man page makes it clear that the filter is a required argument.

Comment: To modify a file in place, use `jq . file.json | sponge file.json` (this requires `sponge` from `moreutils`)

Comment: How is this different from `jq . file.json > file.json`?

Comment: @SteveAnderson - if a process opens a file, processes it line-by-line, and outputs each line, then the output pipe will clobber that file, potentially while it's in use. This is sometimes fine, but to be 100% certain it's OK, use sponge, which buffers.

Comment: This technically worked for me, but I don't know why it slowed my (relatively new w/ no other problems) computer down to nearly a standstill. File size was only 5kb. Maybe because it had Chinese characters in it?

Comment: I had a large list of files I wanted to format in-place; thanks for the sponge reference, that helped a ton: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'jq . "{}"|sponge "{}"' \;`